# ¿Por qué tengo que apretar 2 veces un botón para que funcione mí jsp?

Tags: jsp

Buenas tardes.
Tengo un problema a la hora de pasar registros de una tabla a otra, para que funcione, se debe de escribir el identificador de la persona y apretar el botón "Revisado", pero para que la persona pase a la tabla de revisados, tengo que hacer la acción anterior 2 veces y no sé por qué, este es mí código:

Código de mí botón

```
<button onclick="mensaje(this.form)" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color: #7b123f; color: white; font-size: 18px; float:left; margin-right: 220px; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #7b123f;"><span>Revisado </span></button>
```

Esta parte es para mandar mensaje de confirmación cuando se aprieta el botón "Revisado"

```
try
                    {
                        String id = request.getParameter("Boleta");
                        r = s.executeQuery("SELECT *, IFNULL(SApellido, '') SApellido2 FROM ComunidadPositivo WHERE Identificador = '" + id + "' AND Tipo = 'Alumno'");
                        
                    if(r.next())
                            {
                                String no = r.getString("Nombre");
                                String pap = r.getString("PApellido");
                                String sap = r.getString("SApellido2");
                                
                                out.println("<script>function mensaje(form){var r = confirm('¿Esta seguro de haber revisado a: " + no + " " + pap + " " + sap + "? ' );"
                        + "if (r === true) {"
                        + "datos.action = 'cambioTabla.jsp';"
                        + "datos.submit();"
                        + "} else {"
                        + "}"
                        + "form.submit();"
                        + "}</script>");
                            }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException error)
                    {
                         out.print(error.toString());
                    }
```

Si da confirma que ya revisó, me manda a otro JSP que es "cambioTabla.jsp" y este es el código

```
try {
            String id = request.getParameter("Boleta");  
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            ResultSet rs = null;
            Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/COVID19", "gerardo1", "n0m3l0");
            Statement comando = conexion.createStatement();
            comando.executeUpdate("UPDATE ComunidadPositivo SET Revisado = '" + "Si" + "', Fecha_Revisado = '" + dateFormat.format(date) + "' WHERE Revisado = 'No'"
            + "AND Identificador='" + id + "';");
            conexion.close();
            response.sendRedirect("casosSinAtender.jsp");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Escribí la parte de response.sendRedirect("casosSinAtender.jsp"); para que me mande directamente a otra página, ya que el jsp que se llama "cambioTabla.jsp" no tiene nada.

Comment: Es que en el primer `clic` la función  `mensaje` no existe b(debería dar un error en la consola, entonces hace submit del `buton` y luego de ello recién existe el script. Por lo tanto en el segundo `clic` lo encuentra.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich OK, entiendo, pero, ¿por qué no existe la función en ese momento? Y ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: No existe en ese momento porque se crea recién cuando apretas el boton de "Revisado" en ese momento no ejecuta el  `onclick` pero si el `submit` entonces al refreso del `submit` ya tienes la función. Por eso el segundo `clic`. No sé porque haces eso? ¿por qué el script está como parte de la página al cargar?